# UnsatisfiedLinkError running .jar of alljoyn project, no error when running in Eclipse

Tags: alljoyn

I am creating a simple Alljoyn java application to send and respond to a few signals.  When I run the code in Eclipse (on Win7) it runs fine.  However when I export it as a runnable jar file and attempt to run that I get the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no alljoyn_java in java.library.path
```

The exception is triggered upon calling executing the following code:

```
static {  System.loadLibrary("alljoyn_java");}
```

I have configured the build path of the project to use the external jar alljoyn_java and set the Native library location of that library to the parent directory of the alljoyn_java.dll file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I ended up doing is downloading jarsplice and using that to add the native libraries after I exported the project from Eclipse as a .jar

Answer (score 0):

You have to place the files `alljoyn_java.dll`, `alljoyn_java.lib` and `alljoyn_java.exp` in the same directory of the jar file.

Then, run the jar with the following command:

```
java -jar -Djava.library.path=. [your-jar-file.jar]
```

Answer (score 0):

The JVM looks for native libraries at path specified in **java.library.path** (as mentioned in answer above) and/or path specified in environment variable **LD_LIBRARY_PATH**. Either use the command mentioned in comment above or add path of directory containing your library to environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:<<path_of_dir_containing_lib>>
java -jar <<your_jar_file>>
```

Comment: LD_LIBRAY_PATH works only on Linux not on Windows (as the question request)